# using cmake with mingw-w64 error compiling test program

Tags: gcc, cmake, mingw-w64

I'm trying to do a simple compilation with mingw-w64 and cmake. But for some reason I can't. It fails verifying if gcc can compile a C program which is weird. Any ideas?

Thanks

Paulo

```
C:\work\opencv\myown\hello>cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=gcc
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_8ce25\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/Program
  Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe" is
  not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/work/opencv/myown/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_8ce25\fast"



  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_8ce25\fast"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/work/opencv/myown/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/work/opencv/myown/hello/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 4):

Is `nmake` available in your `PATH`?

You can provide another make command using `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM`, like for instance:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make
```